# Scroll RecyclerView on a button click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to be able to scroll right and left inside a RecyclerView when pressing right and left arrows in addition to the trivial scrolling when swiping

I know this method to scroll to speciffic location in the recycler view

`linearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(2, 20);`

But how can i achieve smooth right and left scrolling when pressing a button

Answer (score 2):

use smoothScrollBy instead of scrollToPosition-

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(dx, dy);
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks, How do i get the current x,y position. the button for scrolling is placed in the Activity not in the RV adapter

Comment: Since it's dx and dy, so you need to care about how many pixels you have to scroll. Like if you want to scroll 100 more pixel, then recyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, 100) for a horizontal scroll view.